# call function each time the variable changes

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

```
<script>
function myFunction(a){

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=a;
}
</script>
```

code to change variable on click

```
<?php

$as=array(0,1,2,3,4,5); 
$a=sizeof($as);
echo'<div class="navbox">
<ul class="nav">';
for($i=1;$i<$a;$i++){

    echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('.$as[$i].')">'.$as[$i].'</li>';
}

$u='<p id="demo"></p>';
echo $u;
ifrm();
function ifrm(){

    global $u;
    if($u=''){

        echo 'empty';
    }
    else{

        $y='index.php?x='.$u;
        echo '<iframe src='.$y.'></frame>';
    }
}
?>
```

call the `function ifrm();` each time the variable $u changes but it calls only ones what should it gets called

Comment: Your question does not make sense. It hurts my head. You need to clarify if you want a response.

Comment: when does the variable $u ever change? if ever, call the function whenever you set the value

Comment: for loop creates the link on click the link the value of $u changes

Comment: Actually what is your requirement?

Comment: i want to change content of iframe and pass  variable whenver i click links @AmGates

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something to be called every time you change the `innerHTML` of the `demo` paragraph. The function `irm()` is server-side, in PHP, so once the page has loaded it cannot be called by JavaScript. You'll have to write this function with the behavior you want in JavaScript, and then call it after you reset the `innerHTML` in `myFunction()`.

PS: I think you want the comparison operator (`if ($u == '')`) in your if statement, not the assignment operator (`=`).

Comment: is it possible to call php function using javascript @eds

Comment: @user1935863 nope - PHP runs on the server (the website's machine), while the page is loading. JavaScript runs on the client (the user's machine), after the page has loaded.

Comment: i want to change content of iframe whenver i click links @eds what should i do